# Second monitor not displaying anything

Tags: display

I recently installed my first Linux distribution. The most recent version of Ubuntu I believe. Upon finally booting up the OS, only one monitor displays anything, but I have a dual monitor setup. The setup works fine when I swap over to Windows.

I have tried entering the display settings through the GUI, but literally no options regarding a second monitor are showing, as if it doesn't detect my second monitor. The only options I have for the display settings are "Resolution", "Orientation", and "Night Light". Above all of these options are the words "Unknown Display", which I'm assuming to be the only display that's being recognized.

Comment: Graphics card? And,  if you installed some,  the drivers version as well,  please.  Also describe your hardware.